# Unable to deploy Bamboo Docker task built image to Azure Web App Container Service get Service Unavailable

Tags: azure-container-service

I'm deploying my builds from Bamboo using Docker tasks to build the image and push to Azure Container Reg from there webhook push to WebApp Container but I get "Service Unavailable", not sure if its my Dockerfile configuration or the platform.

I can build and run the solution local with "docker-compose up dev" and the site comes up on port 8080, this being the exact build and docker config being used in Bamboo tasks.

[docker-compose.yml]

```
   version: '2'
    services:
dev:
 build:
  context: ./
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  environment:
    - NODE_ENV=dev
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  command: yarn start

prod:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: Dockerfileprod
  environment:
  - NODE_ENV=production
  volumes:
    - ./:/app
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  command: node express.js
```

[/docker-compose.yml]

[Dockerfile]:

```
    FROM node:8.11.1

    ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL error

    RUN mkdir -p /app
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY ./ ./

    RUN yarn install --pure-lockfile
    RUN yarn cache clean
```

[/Dockerfile]

Answer (score 0):

So Web Apps doesn't support docker-compose just yet. So in your Dockerfile need to have everything it needs to start the process\application.